# C++ equivalent of perror?

Tags: c++, error-handling

As far as I'm aware, my two options for handling stream errors are `perror` and stream exceptions. Both options are undesirable. Here's why:

**perror**

- `std::strerror` returns an implementation-defined message. This message is not always useful on all systems
- `std::strerror` is not thread-safe
- The pointer returned by `std::strerror` can be invalidated
- The C library is technically "deprecated" in C++. There's almost always a C++-ish equivalent. There's no reason why I should have to rely on POSIX and C when there's a potential C++ equivalent

**stream exceptions**

- Exceptions are not appropriate for every program
- While `std::strerror` can sometimes provide a useful error message, stream exceptions *never* provide a useful error message. With `f.exceptions(f.failbit)`, for both failure to open a file or failure to extract, the exception thrown is `std::ios_base::failure` and the `what()` is "`basic_ios::clear`".

**system_error**

Replacing `std::ios_base::failure` with `std::system_error` produces exactly the same results. If we take a look at [`N2769: Detailed Reporting for Input/Output Library Errors (Revision 2)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2769.htm), we can see why:

> When throwing `ios_base::failure` exceptions, implementations are
>   encouraged to provide values of `ec` that identify the specific reason
>   for the failure.  [***Note*** - Errors arising from the operating
>   system would typically be reported as `system_category` errors with an
>   error value of the error number reported by the operating system.
>   Errors arising from within the stream library would typically be
>   reported as  `error_code(ioerrc::stream, iostream_category`) -- ***end
>   note***].
>
> ***The above wording provides only normative encouragement for implementers to do the right thing, and thus relies on market forces
>   and the good intensions of implementers to produce results useful to
>   users. Anything stronger (such as changing "are encouraged to" to
>   "shall") would require much additional specification and is beyond the
>   scope of what the LWG can realistically tackle for C++0x.***

The alternative is to potentially rely on a bulky third party library (I'm looking at you Boost) or to hand-roll it (which you never want to do unless you know what you're doing.) I'm looking for the C++ standard library way to do this. Is there any?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've added details to why that solution wouldn't work either.

Comment: In POSIX, there’s `strerror_r()`.

Comment: It is fairly inevitable to eventually discover that the standard library is based on a quaint outdated machine model that dates from the 70s, back in the days of "not a bicycle" error reporting and operating systems that were little more than terminal servers.  It survived because it is the lowest common denominator.  There is no magic bullet, you'll end up ripping it all out again and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with you on

> perror et alii are member of C standard library and as such technically deprecated(*).

Well even on cplusplus.com if not an official documentation source, I see for errno:

> C++11 expands the basic set of values required to be defined in this header... In C++, errno is always declared as a macro, but in C it may also be implemented as an int object with external linkage.

My understanding of those sentences is that `errno` is still considered in C++11!

I can even see later

> Libraries that support multi-threading shall implement errno in a per-thread basis: With each thread having its own local errno. This is a requirement in libraries compliant with C11 and C++11 standards.

it means that even if `strerror()` is not thread-safe, `errno` is in any C++11 compliant implementation.

It is now up to you to use `std::strerror` in a synchronized function (for example protected with a mutex) to build a `std::string` if you like. But anyway, even if every documentation on `strerror` states that it uses a static buffer that could be overwritten (that's why Posix 1 defines strerror_r), I could not find any warning on `perror` not beeing thread safe.

(*) My *opinion* on that is that whenever OO and templates can give a nicer interface (iostream vs stdio.h or string vs. string.h), elements of the C library are *replaced* by others in C++ library. But when there is nothing to add (cerrno, cmath, csignal, etc.) the functions from C standard library are simply included in C++ one.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX has `strerror_r()` and Windows has `strerror_s()`.  Note that there have been several incompatible functions called `strerror_r()` out there, so use your feature-test macros.